# Is it safe to use 2FA within a password manager relative to using a separate app for 2FA?

Tags: password-management, account-security, multi-factor

Nowadays, many Password managers offer options for 2-Factor Authentication such as TOTP. I am really confused regarding this. Isn't the whole point of 2FA is to prove you have a second way of proving your identity?

What kind of security risks would I have if I have both my passwords and 2FA within the same app compared to having them in different separate apps? Does having them within a single app pose any significant risk?

Comment: Related: [Is it secure to store a two factor authentication seed in a password manager?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/150448/129883)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. What do you mean by "have both my passwords and 2FA within the same app"? Storing passwords and offering TOTP are different things. This is possibly a duplicate oth either of those things, but you need to clarify what you mean.

Comment: @FireQuacker That's the question I was searching for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of security risks would I have if I have both my passwords and 2FA within the same app?

What is your threat scenario?

It's convenient. On my laptop, both are available without any external devices. If I log on a website on a computer I don't own, I look up the password and OTP on my phone. The attacker in this scenario will get password, but not secret for 2FA - thus it thwarts many attacks in case of key loggers.

It also thwarts password leaks. If my password is leaked from another site, due to password re-use, 2FA will thwart attackers.

It obviously provides *less* security than a physical token, as malware on my computer may access the secret - something which is impossible with for instance a Yubikey.

Like so many other security features it's a trade-off between usability and security. It's better security, especially in some scenarios, than no 2FA, and it's weaker than a proper hardware token. It's more convenient than a hardware token, but less secure. It's cheaper than a hardware token, but also less secure...

I use both. For some sites, that would be inconvenient but not fatal to loose access to I use Bitwarden. For others, I carry a Yubikey. So in short - carry out a threat assessment. Who are you protecting against, and what attacks can they mount against you? There's no universal answer; it's a trade-off *you* have to make for **your** use case.

Comment: Hopefully there wouldn't be any password reuse if it's a password manager.

Comment: Sure, but it's a type of breach that it *would* protect against. It would also work against shoulder surfing.

Comment: Edited my question. I was looking for what new risks are there when using two separate apps for 2FA & password manager compared to combining them into one app i.e) using 2FA within the password manager.

Comment: Broadly same. If it's one app, one compromise is enough. If it's separate app, both will have to be compromised. It's a security trade-off *you* have to make - convenience vs. security.

Comment: I think this last comment should be included in the answer.